# How to prove the cubic formula without root extraction

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to prove the cubic formula, in the following form:

> Given a field $F$ and $x,p,q\in F$, define $m=\frac p3$ and $n=\frac q2$, and suppose also that $\gamma,\tau$ are given such that $\gamma^2=n^2+m^3$ and $\tau^3=\gamma-n\ne0$. Then $x^3+px+q=0$ if and only if $x=\omega\tau-\frac m{\omega\tau}$ for some $\omega$ satisfying $\omega^3=1$.

(I have already reduced the statement from the more general $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ by a linear transformation.) The usage of $\gamma$ and $\tau$ substitutes for the extraction of square and cube roots, and allows me to stick to just field axioms in the proof - ideally I want this proof to work for any field with characteristic other than $2$ or $3$.

But making this approach work with [Cardano's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method) is giving me some issues. Since the reverse implication is just a matter of algebra with the given expressions of $\tau,\gamma$, suppose that we are given $x$ such that $x^3+px+q=0$; we want to find some root of unity $\omega$ satisfying $x=\omega\tau-\frac m{\omega\tau}$. The key of Cardano's method is to observe that the conditions $u+v=x$, $uv+m=0$ together with the condition on $x$ yields a quadratic polynomial $z^2+qz-m^3=0$ whose roots are $u^3$, $v^3$, and solving this with the quadratic equation gives something amenable to a cube root extraction.

But why can we choose such $u,v$ in the first place? Equivalently, why should we expect a priori that the "substitution" $x=u-\frac mu$ has a solution in $u$? It follows from the quadratic formula, with discriminant $x^2+4m$, but I see no reason to believe that this is a square given only $\gamma$ and $\tau$.

If we assume that there is a $\Delta^2=x^2+4m$, then $u=\frac x2+\Delta$ and $v=\frac x2-\Delta$ solve the equations, so we can proceed as normal: $u^6+qu^3-m^3=0$, so by the quadratic formula with discriminant $q^2+4m^3=(2\gamma)^2$, we get $u^3=-n\pm\gamma$ and $v^3=-n\mp\gamma$; in one case we have $u^3=\gamma-n=\tau^3$ so $\frac u\tau$ is the desired root of unity, and in the other case $\frac v\tau$ is the desired root of unity (since $x=u-\frac mu=v-\frac mv$).

Comment: Update: this question was used in the construction of a [Metamath formalization of the cubic formula](http://us2.metamath.org:88/mpegif/cubic.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your property is indeed true except possibly when $\gamma=0$, i.e. when $x^3+px+q$ has a double root.

If $\gamma\neq 0$, taking $\Delta=\frac{(mx^2-nx+2m^2)}{\gamma}$
you are done; notice the identity
$$ (mx^2-nx+2m^2)^2=(n^2+m^3)(x^2+4m)+m(mx-2n)(x^3+px+q).$$

If $\gamma=0$ then $n=-\tau^3\neq 0$ by hypothesis, and $x^3+px+q$ can be rewritten as
$x^3-3\tau^2x-2\tau^3=(x+\tau)^2(x-2\tau)$. If $x=2\tau$, your property is true with $\omega=1$. If $x=-\tau$ however, your property is true iff $F$ contains a primitive third root of unity. This is false when $F={\mathbb Q}$ and $\tau=1$ for example.

Comment: Nice job with the identity - I knew the answer would be something like that, but various ansatze gave me no results and there are quite a lot of ways to add a $x^3+px+q$ to the expression. To add a little more to the counterexample, note that in the case $\tau=1$, $\gamma=0$, $x=-1$, the equation $\Delta^2=x^2+4m$ becomes $\Delta^2=-3$, so we need to find an element like $i\sqrt3$, which is exactly what is needed to construct the usual primitive third root of unity $e^{2i\pi/3}=\frac12(i\sqrt 3-1)$ in $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 1):

$x^3+px+q$ *does* have at most three roots in the algebraic closure of $F$.

Meanwhile, given the existence of $\gamma$ and $\tau$, and if necessary taking $\omega$ in the algebraic closure of $F$, we can just verify that each of $\tau-\frac{m}{\tau}$, $\omega\tau-\frac{m}{\omega\tau}$, and $\omega^2\tau-\frac{m}{\omega^2\tau}$ are roots. Characterizing all three at once as $\omega^i\tau-\frac{m}{\omega^i\tau}$, we can see:
$$
\begin{align}
&\left(\omega^i\tau-\frac{m}{\omega^i\tau}\right)^3+p\left(\omega^i\tau-\frac{m}{\omega^i\tau}\right)+q\\
&=\tau^3-3m\omega^i\tau+3\frac{m^2}{\omega^i\tau}-\frac{m^3}{\tau^3}+p\omega^i\tau-p\frac{m}{\omega^i\tau}+q\\
&=\tau^3-p\omega^i\tau+\frac{mp}{\omega^i\tau}-\frac{m^3}{\tau^3}+p\omega^i\tau-p\frac{m}{\omega^i\tau}+q\\
&=\tau^3-\frac{m^3}{\tau^3}+q\\
&=\gamma-n-\frac{m^3}{\gamma-n}+q\\
&=\gamma-n-\frac{m^3(\gamma+n)}{\gamma^2-n^2}+q\\
&=\gamma-n-\frac{m^3(\gamma+n)}{m^3}+q\\
&=\gamma-n-(\gamma+n)+q\\
&=-2n+q\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$

Assume for the moment that the three roots that were just demonstrated are distinct. Then, if  you had an $x$ that was a root of $x^3+px+q$, whether $x$ was in $F$ or not, it *has* to equal one of these three demonstrated roots, which are each of the form $$(\text{cubic root of $1$})\tau-\frac{m}{(\text{cubic root of $1$})\tau}$$ as required.

If the three demonstrated roots are not distinct, there is a little more to think through.

Comment: I guess that "if the roots are distinct" corresponds with "$\gamma\ne0$" in Ewan's answer, so this is an alternate proof using the one directional FTA (a cubic has at most three roots). Although if you assume the roots are distinct then you don't need the algebraic closure because $F$ has all the roots of unity to begin with (this follows from the assumptions on $\gamma$ and $\tau$ if you piece together some work in the OP and Ewan's identity).